# How to bind two UdpClients to the same port?

Tags: c#

My problem is that I have more than one instance of my class, while trying to listen the same port. I've found that I can do it (listen on the same port) with the code I found (using the "ReuseAddress"), however it only works with multicast and broadcast packets, whilst I need unicast packets.

Anyone knows how I can make it work with unicast aswell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, since UDP does not support the concept of a connection, it's usually not possible to bind multiple UDP sockets to the same local address:port pair. What you can do, however, is write your own wrapper around a single, shared UDP socket that figures out which client an incoming packet comes from, and routes it to the appropriate point within your own code.